# Indexed DB - Database Undefined after being deleted and giving another name

Tags: indexeddb

i have the following code that creates a database and allows me to perform basic operations on it which normally works fine (i know its not the most elegant of code yet im just testing for an assignment at the minute :P ).....however when i use the delete function and refresh the page (including after wiping all browsing data etc) the database does not open again and i get an undefined error, any ideas as to why this is happening?

p.s. i know the database has  diff name than in the delete function, this was me trying to make a new one

```
// Browser support detection
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

    // Transaction object for use with CRUD
    var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;



    (function () {     

        var db;

        var memberInfo = [
            { memID: "001", forename: "John", surname: "Smith", dob: "23/01/1987", password: "password123", gID: "1" },
            { memID: "002", forename: "Bob", surname: "Smith", dob: "17/05/1934", password: "password123", gID: "2" },
            { memID: "003", forename: "Frank", surname: "Smith", dob: "17/05/1990", password: "password123", gID: "2" },
            { memID: "004", forename: "Alan", surname: "Smith", dob: "17/05/1985", password: "password123", gID: "1" },
            { memID: "005", forename: "Tony", surname: "Smith", dob: "17/05/1978", password: "password123", gID: "3" }

        ];



        var gradeInfo = [
            { gID: "1", type: "GOLD", cost: "£200.00" },
            { gID: "2", type: "SILVER", cost: "£125.00" },
            { gID: "3", type: "BRONZE", cost: "£75.00" }

        ];

        var facInfo = [
            { memID: "001", factype: "Squash"},
            { memID: "001", factype: "Martial Arts"},
            { memID: "002", factype: "Swimming"},
            { memID: "004", factype: "Squash"},
            { memID: "004", factype: "Tennis"},
            { memID: "004", factype: "Swimming"},
            { memID: "005", factype: "Football"},
            { memID: "005", factype: "Archery"}

        ];




        function initDb() {


            // Open call is used to open database with given name & set DB version
            var request = indexedDB.open("HaleSportsClub", 1); 

            // Function used to get database object from request and store for user
            request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                db = request.result;                                                
            };

            request.onerror = function (evt) {
                alert("Database did not open: " + evt.target.message); // !!!!!
            };

            // Fire when version is smaller than one provided (by open call)
            request.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) { 

                var db = evt.target.result;

                // Each object store resembles a table in RDBMS              
                var memberObject = db.createObjectStore("members", { keyPath: "memID" });
                var gradeObject = db.createObjectStore("grades", { keyPath: "gID" });
                var facObject = db.createObjectStore("facilities", { keyPath: "memID" });

                // Creates searchable indexes (??)

                memberObject.createIndex("forename", "forename", { unique: false });
                memberObject.createIndex("surname", "surname", { unique: false });
                memberObject.createIndex("gID", "gID", { unique: false });
                facObject.createIndex("memID", "memID", { unique: false });


                for (i in memberInfo) {
                    memberObject.add(memberInfo[i]);
                }


                for (i in gradeInfo) {
                    gradeObject.add(gradeInfo[i]);
                }

                for (i in facInfo) {
                    facObject.add(facInfo[i]);
                } 



            };

            request.onblocked = function (evt){

                alert("database currently being upgraded, try again soon");
            }

        }



        function contentLoaded() {

            initDb();
```

// This area contains functions to add/delete etc but i have taken out for purposes of this question

```
        }



        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentLoaded, false); // starts functions

})();
```

I used this code to delete the database:

```
   function delDB() {

                    var dbreq = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("HSC_Member_Database");

                    try{
                        dbreq.onsuccess = function (event) {
                            var output = document.getElementById("printOutput");
                            output.innerHTML = "deleted";

                        }

                        dbreq.onerror = function (event) {
                            console.log("Database error code: " + event.target.errorCode);
                        }

                    }catch(e){
                        console.log("Database error code: " + e.target.errorCode);
                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try when hitting problems after upgrade is to increment your database version number:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("HaleSportsClub", 2);
```